# Relation between Bessel K functions

Tags: integration, analysis, bessel-functions

I am studying Bessel modified $K_\nu$ functions, and I do not find any clear reference for the following question: is there a relation between $K_\nu(x)$ and $K_\mu(x)$ in general?

More specifically, I would like to know the relation (which can be merely bounds or asymptotics) between $K_{a+it}(x)$ and $K_{it}(x)$.

Comment: Asymptotics with respect to what?

Comment: Are you aware of the book "A treatise on the theory of Bessel functions" by G.N. Watson? Maybe you'll find something in there. Sorry I can't help you more...

Comment: There are several identities [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselK/17/01/), but I'm not sure you're going to find the specific one of interest.